# Secondary Router Blocks Primary Router's wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

My ISP gave me ZTE H3600 router, due to its lack of performance in data transfer I bought new router which is TPlink AX5400. So I set tplink one as primary router which gets internet directly from ONT(optical network terminal) and set zte one as secondary to use as an access point.

The config of routers are:
Primary router : tplink
DHCP enabled
IP pool: 192.168.0.2-192.168.0.253

Secondary router: zte
DHCP disabled
gateway address is 192.168.1.1
IP pool: 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.253
firewall is off

Secondary router connection to primary is ethernet cable at either LAN port.

The problem is, when i try to connect wifi of primary router, it says "sign in to network" and direct me to secondary router's setting page. Moreover, secondary router's wifi doesnt have internet as well.

Basically, both router's wifi is blocked.

At first, i thought wifi waves are overlapping,so I tried to change channels of routers to optimal channels which wont block each other. However, it did not work.

Secondary router ZTE H3600 does not have bridge mode or acceess point mode in its settings since it has shitty ISP's firmware in it.

Routers is connected LAN to LAN

TPlink DHCP Settings:

[TPlink DHCP ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooOSd.png)

ZTE DHCP Settings:

[ZTE  DHCP ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZo4u.png)

Sign in to Network error when I try to connect primary (tplink one) router's wifi:

[Sign in to Network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEquW.png)

Comment: `gets internet directly from ONT` `sign in to internet` sounds like you haven't set up the modem part of it right? Maybe you should consult your ISP? (Or by ONT do you mean a separate modem device?) Can you identify whether the "sign in page" is created by tplink or your ISP (or some other vendor)?

Comment: I made some edits in question thanks for pointing out. well modem part is ONT, ONT has fiber optic cable input and ethernet output. I already consult ISP they say "I must use their router as primary router" which I dont want to since their router is really bad. sign in network page, is like when you try to connect public network such as wifi at airport. So, when i connect to primary router's wifi, there is a notification which says sign in to network and when I press it directs me to secondary routers settings page.

Comment: @Jsennin I think you should still be able to access the tplink's admin portal by entering its LAN IP in a browser, right? If you do so, can you check its WAN info and see if it got any WAN IP assigned? Probably you need to configure it to do PPPoE or something like that. (You may want to check the same setting section in your ZTE admin portal and see if you can find any necessary login info / setting parameters with this regard that you need to "reuse" in your tplink.)

Comment: Yeah I already copied the PPoE and mac address of ZTE to tplink, otherwise I wont get internet access

Comment: I don't understand. So you get Internet access when you connect a host to the tplink's LAN port, but not if you connect to its WiFi? Does this happen if you do not hook the zte to the tplink?

Comment: I get internet access from tplink's LAN and wifi normally, however when I connected zte to tplink. zte blocks tplinks wifi LAN still works though. And I don't understand how zte can block tplink wifi, I mean why when I try to connect tplinks wifi it redirect me to zte setting page to " sign in to network"

Comment: they are connected LAN to LAN

Comment: I'm already trying to use ZTE as an AP. However it blocks primary (tplink) router's wifi. I edited first post. Now, it shows DHCP server settings on both routers and error page when I try to connect tplink wifi. I think the settings you described already set, but it is still giving same error when I try to connect tplink wifi.

Comment: Yeah I want to have 1 network , did you check both DHCP settings in the picture

Comment: Gotcha, I missed that you had disabled the DHCP on the ZTE device. since you included its configuration I had assumed you wanted two networks. Ill clean up my comments.

Comment: I don't understand why this configuration is 2 network config.  Could you explain to me? My aim in this just increase my wifi range using ZTE router as a secondary router. Since extending primary wifi is not recommended, I want ZTE to create Wifi in different room so every place in my home have access to wifi.

Comment: When zte was my secondary router, It asks me to sign in to access the network of primary router. So, when I try to connect tplink wifi which is my primary router, I am directed to zte sign-in page.